# Is there a difference between git mv and the MS-DOS move?

Tags: git, git-mv

#### Question

Does it make a difference if I move Git tracked files with the [`git mv`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) command as opposed to just moving the files with MS-DOS [`move`](http://www.computerhope.com/movehlp.htm) or the Windows Explorer?

Back in the Subversion days, it was necessary to use for example the TortoiseSVN [`SVN Move versioned files here`](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html) command to keep the history intact.

I would have expected it to work the same way in Git, but a test (see example below) showed that Git detects by itself that the file has been moved and that the history is kept intact.

So why use `git mv` at all?

#### Example

```
C:\test>git init
C:\test>mkdir folder
C:\test>cd folder
C:\test\folder>echo "1" > file.txt
C:\test\folder>git add .
C:\test\folder>git commit -m "Initial commit"
C:\test\folder>echo "2" >> file.txt
C:\test\folder>git add .
C:\test\folder>git commit -m "Update file.txt"
C:\test\folder>move file.txt ..
C:\test\folder>cd ..

C:\test>git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    folder/file.txt

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        file.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

C:\test>git add -A
C:\test>git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        renamed:    folder/file.txt -> file.txt

C:\test>git commit -m "Moved file.txt with the move command"
```

The entire history has been retained despite not using `git mv` and Git says that is has detected a renaming.

```
C:\test>git log --oneline --follow file.txt
6bd3c05 Moved file.txt with the move command
5b55aea Update file.txt
5b9b255 Initial commit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git mv` does the staging for you as well, so that you don't need to `git rm olfdfile` and `git add newfile` after physically moving the file via `mv`/`MOVE`/`explorer.exe`.

This is [on purpose](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_does_Git_not_.22track.22_renames.3F).

Answer (score 6):

When you use `git mv` it will index the modifications for you

If you do it manually with your OS, you will need to do

```
git add -A <previous-path-to-file-that-was-moved>
git add <new-path-to-file>
```

So that git understands you actually renamed the file.

Comment: If you simply do `git add .` after a manual move, will this work? I'm asking for auto-generated html files through a static generator like pelican which reside on the `gh-pages` branch. Since several new files are added/removed on each build, you can't be expected to separately run a git command for each file?